# Is there a way to save Eclipse workspace state and reload again during power cycle, something similar feature like Virtualbox machine state save

Tags: eclipse

I am working on c/c++ cdt eclipse project. During code analysis, there will be many search for function names, variables etc.. (search tab) pinned individual tabs.. if the situation comes to restart the eclipse or the machine, I would like to know if there is any is any option to save these tabs (with search results, just like the feature in virtualbox machine state save option) ..

Tried eclipse,
Expectation : to see all the current search results after reopening the eclipse
Resulted : only (pinned) search tabs with no search content

Comment: Hello. By default, a normal shutdown of Eclipse (as opposed to a process termination) will save the state of the workspace in terms of open perspectives and views and tabs. The data in those may come from elsewhere and result from various types of web/network calls and be from a sequence of calls or custom calculations to remote places that may or may not need authentication. It's therefore not possible to ensure the data in any of these views/tabs can be saved. The creator of the view/tab would need to intercept Eclipse shutdown and write something to persist the data to reload at next launch